Untracked directories from the shared repository by the Git panel - VS Code and Visual Studio
I have a git repository that contains an FS project: a database, server (C#), and client (React).
Since there is one common repository, when I change files on the server side by using the Visual Studio IDE, the Git panel in VS Code (the client-side IDE) shows me those changes.
This scenario also happens in the opposite situation, when I change files on the client side by using the VS Code IDE, the changes are also shown to me on the Visual Stodio (serve- side IDE).
I open the server side from a specific solution, And the client side from workspace in the client folder.
Can I hide the git tracked from specific folders?
Also for VS Code and Visual Studio.
(In VS Code I changed settings to git.autoRepositoryDetection = false ,For user settings and workspace settings, But it didn't change anything)
Thanks

is it not just files.exclude? also, pleaes show some info about directory layout and which directories you're opening in which applications.

@starball Thanks! But, files.exclude is removed it, only from Explorer Panel. I want to remove folders from Git panel.

I think this isn‘t possibel, to split tracking changed files in Git per folder. Only if you split your project in two separat Git Repositories (look for Git-submodules, but brings other obstacles!). But why you want use Git-panel in separate IDE? I've never heard/seen this from a developer. All only use the one prefered Git-panel in the preferred IDE.

Because, I want to develop server side with Visual Studio, and client side with VS code. This project is small, so I don't want to separate for 2 repositories, also CI/CD will be complex (Monorepo).

I also use two separate IDEs to develop backend and frontend. But instead of using the Git gui from one of the two IDEs, I use a standalone Git gui product: Fork (https://git-fork.com/, for private use free). And why you don't just choose one? Either one of your IDEs or a standalone. It doesn't matter if you make backend changes that you then add to the version control in the frontend IDE (e.g vscode) Git gui...
